# Tags in Wordpress 3.2

Tags: jquery, tags, ajax

Why I can't add tags since Wordpress 3.2 ?!
Ajax doesn't seem to work...
I gonna be crazy.

Any help please ?

Comment: Keywords? Are you referring to tags?

Comment: Oops ! Yes tags! Sorry. I'll edit it

Comment: First guess this would be a conflict with jquery. jquery updated in version 3.2. Maybe one of your plugins is interfering with jquery? Try disabling all plugins to see if JS functionality is restored.

Comment: @Brady AWESOME MAN ! It was a conflict with jQuery !!! (Disqus Plugin for Wordpress)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this to be an issue with a jQuery conflict.

Since version 3.2 of WP jQuery has been updates. There might be other plugins you are using that doesn't play nice with the new jQuery version which is then triggering a JS error, thus stopping the tag/AJAX functionality from working.

Try disabling all your plugins and see if this fixes the issue. If it does enable one by one to target which plugin is causing the issue.

Once you know what plugin is causing the issue then you can either contact the plugin author for a fix and try asking a question here to see if we can fix it.

Comment: I would also suggest switching to Twenty Eleven while troubleshooting, as Themes *can* cause jQuery conflicts as well.

Comment: Yes, Wordpress 3.2 comes with jQuery 1.6.1